# How can i validate my form outside form in yii 1

Tags: php, forms, yii

I am trying to validate my form But without any model . I am successful to do this and its 70 % done . But i am stuck at one place so i need a small help . For this i have created a custome class.

```
class MyValidator extends CFormModel {
    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($_POST[$name])?$_POST[$name]:null;
    }

    static function myValidate( Array $rules ) {
        $dummy = new MyValidator();

        foreach($rules as $rule) {
            if( isset($rule[0],$rule[1]) ) {
                $validator = CValidator::createValidator( 
                     $rule[1], 
                     $dummy, 
                     $rule[0], 
                     array_slice($rule,2) 
                );
                $validator->validate($dummy);
            }
            else { /* throw error; */ }
        }
        return $dummy;
    }
}
```

Now i am using this class in my controller like

```
$model=MyValidator::myValidate($this->validConfiguration());
if(!$model->hasErrors())
{
    file_put_contents($config,$newconfig);
    $this->refresh();
}else
{
    $this->errors=$model->getErrors(); 
    print_r($this->errors);
    $data=(array) json_decode($newconfig);
}
```

`validConfiguration` is a function contaning rules

```
public function validConfiguration()
{
    return array(
        array('guestuser[email], adminEmail, dateformat', 'required'),
        array('adminEmail, guestuser[email]', 'email'),
        );
}
```

My form fields are like

```
<div>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('adminEmail',isset($data['adminEmail']) ? $data['adminEmail']: '',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
<div class="errorMessage"><?php echo $this->displayerror('adminEmail'); ?></div>
</div>
<div>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('guestuser[email]',isset($data['guestuser']->email) ? $data['guestuser']->email: '',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
<div class="errorMessage"><?php echo $this->displayerror('guestuser[email]'); ?></div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

the code is working well for single elements I.e `adminEmail` `defaultpage` but not working for `guestuser[email]` `guestuser[password]` like this .

Comment: You missed '  array('guestuser[email], adminEmail, dateformat', 'required'),

Comment: @SardorDushamov that was a typing error in example. .